# Complex measures vs. Positive Measures

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

In his real and complex analysis, Rudin writes that the right hand side of the expression $\mu(E) = \Sigma \mu(E_i)$ must necessarily converge for any countable partition $\{E_i\}$ of a measurable E, with respect to any complex measure. He points out that this convergence requirement would not apply to a positive measure. (The first paragraphs of chapter 6.)

This confuses me -

1) I don't see why the definition implies that $\Sigma \mu(E_i)$ must converge unless $\mu(E)$ is given to be finite, 
2) and if $\mu(E)$ is finite, then positive additivity would imply that $\Sigma \mu(E_i)$ converges even if $\mu$ is only a positive measure.

Thank you.

Comment: Rudin defines a complex measure to be finite.  Are you asking why he does so, or did I miss the point of your query?

Comment: I guess I'd be curiuous to know why he does so, but presumably I'll find out when I read that chapter. I didn't realize that a "complex function" precluded taking values at $\infty$, unlike a positive function.

Comment: It's not so much that a complex function cannot take "the" value at $\infty$, though we are apt to call functions that do so nicely on the whole complex plane *meromorphic*.  Rather the *complex measure* is required to be finite (measurable sets always have a measure with finite absolute value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember being a bit surprised in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* that complex measures are [by definition finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Integration_in_respect_to_a_complex_measure), unlike the positive measures he begins by studying.

The Comment that struck you is surely meant to highlight this distinction.

I too wondered "why" this distinction is necessary.  My view is that it comes with having signed measures, since we can no longer unambiguously assign the sum of two measures of disjoint sets to be the measure of their union, if one were to have positive infinity and the other negative infinity as their measures.  Of course the case of adding two positive infinities may be resolved without controversy or ambiguity.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: In short, the countable additivity requires that $$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \mu(E_i)$$ is invariant under rearrangements, that is, "unconditionally convergent", if we allow us to call a series of non-negative terms convergent if its sum is $+\infty$. Every series of non-negative terms is unconditionally convergent in that sense. If you allow the measure to take negative or non-real values too, you either have to demand absolute convergence, or get some hopelessly complicated condition for the admissible measures. Also, if you demand absolute convergence, the space of measures is a vector space.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Wow what a great comment! *(You struck me again and again.)*